# Is a function of conformal ratios invariant under conformal transformations?

Tags: symmetry, conformal-field-theory, scale-invariance

If I have a function $f:=f(r,s)$ a function of the conformal ratios $r$ and $s$ only, i.e. for example:

$$r := \frac{(x1-x2)^2(x3-x4)^2}{(x1-x3)^2(x2-x4)^2} \qquad, \qquad s := \frac{(x1-x4)^2(x2-x3)^2}{(x1-x3)^2(x2-x4)^2}, \tag{1}$$

is $f$ automatically invariant under conformal transformations?

Comment: Can you show some work on your attempts to answer this question? If you already know the definition of a conformal transformation, it seems like this is something you could easily check. If you are not familiar with conformal transformations or you do not know how to apply them to answering this question then this would be useful to know when writing an answer.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt Thank you for your answer and for your suggestion. I think I figured it out in the following way: a function is conformal if applying the conformal generators on it yield $0$. Using the chain rule, it is clear that any function will vanish under the SCT (Special Conformation Transformations). The other transformations, such as scaling, can be checked in the same way. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to check. You can also directly apply finite conformal transformations to these expressions to check their invariance. SCTs are the only transformations for which this isn't automatic.

Comment: @SethWhitsitt Nice, thank you!